# Texture not loaded

Tags: c++, sfml

I have problem loading textures and fonts in SFML.

This is my code:

```
#include <SFML/graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>

#pragma comment (lib, "sfml-graphics.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "sfml-window.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "sfml-system.lib")

int main ()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::ViewMode(X, Y), "The Chess!");
    //load the texture
    sf::Texture texture;
    texture.loadFromFile("chessbck.png");
    if(!texture)
        // An error has been occurred
        MessageBox(NULL, "Error!", "error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
    sf::Sprite sprite(texture);
    window.clear(sf::Color(0, 0, 0));
    // Clear the window with black color.
    window.draw(sprite);
    // Draw the sprite
    window.display();
     // And finaly,... display the window.
}
```

Please help me!

This is a picture from the console:

[image: Console]

I check the directory but it's true.

Also, this occurs when I load fonts.

Comment: `if (!texture)` will not check for the error... `if (!texture.`[`loadFromFile()`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/classsf_1_1Texture.php#a8e1b56eabfe33e2e0e1cb03712c7fcc7)`)` will... Since the function is the one that returns a boolean for you to check... What you are doing can be interpreted as `if (!sf::Texture(texture))`...

Comment: The problem is resolved: I should select Release.